# Protecting negative power rail

Tags: protection, circuit-protection, ldo, over-voltage-protection, negative-voltage

I don't trust my power supply and want to protect my circuitry from over(under)-voltage, but cannot find a clear path of going forward with negative power rail. LDO which I use ([LT3094](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt3094.html)) is rated for 500mA. If that matters - LDO input is -12V, output -10.5V.

#### Update 1

-10.5V was chosen purely because of dissipation, but there's headroom. I can easily go down to -7V if that matters (obviously, if input voltage is dropped too). Max ambient temperature, as per requirement, is 60C. Calculated current on this rail is 300mA.

Power supply (subject to change) is [Traco Power TXLN 035-22M2](https://www.tracopower.com/sites/default/files/products/datasheets/txln035_datasheet.pdf).

#### Update 2

To be clear, I want to protect input to negative power rail LDO, not power supply input.

#### Question 2

Is a crowbar circuit applicable in this scenario? Similar to positive rail to ground, but with ground to negative power rail? Can this LDO withstand this mishappen?

Comment: Instead of adding a bunch of components that may or may not protect the rest of your circuit, why not fix the problem and get a power supply you can trust?

Comment: @vir Power supply comes from a 3rd party, external board. It works flawlessly, but I want to make sure RMA is never involved regarding this manner.

Comment: The external power supply you linked says it has OVP. The regulator has internal thermal shutdown unless you exceed the input voltage limit of -20 or -22V. Will glomping on additional circuitry really improve the situation? If you think so, then what worst case situation are you trying to protect against? -300V? 240VAC? It's likely possible, but at a cost. Reverse polarity protection might not be a bad idea.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany If I understood it correctly, power supply has OVP for input, not output. To be clear, I want to protect LDO input, not PSU input.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks for the tip about reverse polarity, that's something I'm looking at ATM as well.

Comment: OVP is a redundant circuit that independently protects against overvoltage appearing at the output of the power supply (in order to protect the load). In this case, only output 1 has OVP and it will operate between 115 - 140% of Vout nom. according to the datasheet. So with 12V nominal output, the fault voltage should never exceed 16.8V.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany PSU datasheet says "Overvoltage Protection 115 - 140% of Vout nom. (only Output 1)" So it does have overvoltage protection on the output... but only on the positive output.

Comment: I'd just use an LDO with higher input voltage rating. The LDO will then survive any voltage the PSU can output in worst case. The LDO will protect itself from thermal overload, so if the input voltage is high for long enough time to overheat the LDO, the LDO will shut down. I genuinely don't think you need any other protection than polarity. The only PSU failure that would produce higher output would be if the switcher control loop got stuck open and any built-in protections have failed. In that case, there still is only so high that output can go. A simple 7908 will take up to -35V.

Comment: There's no need to protect from a primary-to-secondary failure where mains would be imposed on the secondary, since when that happens, the positive and negative rails will be connected to mains until the primary side fuse built into the supply opens. This is a very rare failure and you'd need extensive testing to ensure any protection scheme works, otherwise it'll be just an illusion of protection.

Comment: *I want to make sure RMA is never involved regarding this manner* Whoa, whoa, you've done a failure tree analysis and you have figured out the relative likelihood of various failures, right? You'll be OK getting an RMA regarding other manners? Because I doubt you've excluded most other failure modes - not until you do a formal analysis. Switching power supplies usually fail with dead outputs, not with overvoltage. It'd take some work to make a case that this protection is worth the effort.

Comment: I'd like to stress what Kuba… has said: adding more components to any device does primarily make it *less* reliable. The protective functionality of the components must outweigh that! As far as I can tell from your question and the discussion here, it would seem you're not actually solving a reliability issue, but are introducing extra reliability problems. I'd advise to not do that!

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments! You convinced me to drop OVP circuitry since in this particular case it is questionable whether there's really a need for it.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica If you copy-paste your comments into answer, I will gladly accept it. Thanks again.